# Debian - install missing man pages?

Tags: debian, apt, man

I run [RaspBMC](http://www.raspbmc.com/) - a distro based on [Raspbian](http://www.raspbian.org/), that's a custom minimal Debian for the [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/).

If I recall correctly, the `man` utility is NOT installed by default with RaspBMC (although I may be mistaken).

The problem is, packages installed prior to installing the actual `man` utility do not install their man pages. This includes the packages that come pre-installed with the system.

Example: I tried with udisks-glue (which comes pre-installed)

```
$ man udisks-glue
No manual entry for udisks-glue
```

After re-installing that package, the man page is there.

```
$ apt-get remove udisks-glue
$ apt-get install udisks-glue
$ man udisks-glue
[Man page gets displayed]
```

**The question is: can I somehow install *all* the missing man pages easily?**

From what I can see, installing the man pages is a step that's run for each `apt-get install` command:

```
Unpacking udisks-glue (from .../udisks-glue_1.3.4-1_armhf.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
[...]
```

Using divide-and-conquer, I assume this could be obtained by:

1. getting a list of all installed packages ( `dpkg -l | grep ??? | cut ??? | ???` )
2. finding a way to tell apt-get to re-install a package without messing with the config (a `remove + install` kinda fits the bill, but I don't think it plays nice with dependencies)
   EDIT: [this should do it](https://superuser.com/a/450620):
   `sudo apt-get install --reinstall packagename`
3. run 2. over each item in 1.

Is this the (simplest) way to go?

**Update**

I remembered I bricked RaspBMC once doing `apt-get upgrade`, so I want to make sure the packages are NOT upgraded to newer versions when reinstalling (which seems to be the case with `apt-get install --reinstall` by default.

Comment: Another copy, on the Raspberry Pi site: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7918/raspbmc-install-missing-man-pages

Answer (score 5):

Starting from @derobert's answer, I worked my way to getting exactly the current version of all packages to reinstall.

Short version:

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep '^ii ' | sed 's/  */\t/g' |cut -f 2,3 | sed 's/\t/=/' | xargs apt-get install --reinstall -y --ignore-missing
```

Explained:

The key is actually specifying the required version of each package.

The general command is:

```
apt-get install --reinstall <package>=<version>
```

Breaking down the long command line:

```
$ dpkg -l

Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                                        Version                            Architecture Description
+++-===========================================================-==================================-============-========================================================================
ii  adduser                                                     3.113+nmu3                         all          add and remove users and groups
ii  apt                                                         0.9.7.8+rpi1                       armhf        commandline package manager
ii  apt-utils                                                   0.9.7.8+rpi1                       armhf        package managment related utility programs
ii  aptitude-common                                             0.6.8.2-1                          all          architecture indepedent files for the aptitude package manager
ii  atmel-firmware                                              1.3-4                              all          Firmware for Atmel at76c50x wireless networking chips.

$ dpkg -l | grep '^ii '
```

...gets rid of the header lines and a few packages with status '`hold`' (marked as `hi` instead of `ii`)

```
$ dpkg -l | grep '^ii ' | sed 's/  */\t/g'
```

... converts any number of spaces to a single TAB character, preparing the ground for `cut`.
(Btw: why, oh why, doesn't `sed` support `x+` regex for "character x, one or more times"? It can be emulated with `xx*` - meaning 'x' once followed by 'x' zero or more times)

The output looks like this:

```
ii      adduser 3.113+nmu3      all     add     and     remove  users   and     groups
ii      apt     0.9.7.8+rpi1    armhf   commandline     package manager
ii      apt-utils       0.9.7.8+rpi1    armhf   package managment       related utility programs
ii      aptitude-common 0.6.8.2-1       all     architecture    indepedent      files   for     the     aptitude        package manager
ii      atmel-firmware  1.3-4   all     Firmware        for     Atmel   at76c50x        wireless        networking      chips.
```

Next:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep '^ii ' | sed 's/  */\t/g' | cut -f 2,3 | sed 's/\t/=/'
```

...gets the name **and version** of each package (the 2nd and 3rd fields), and replaces the tab that separates them with an '='

```
adduser=3.113+nmu3
apt=0.9.7.8+rpi1
apt-utils=0.9.7.8+rpi1
aptitude-common=0.6.8.2-1
atmel-firmware=1.3-4
```

Finally, pipe each of the above to apt-get as a long list of arguments using `xargs`.

Notice the parameter `--ignore-missing` - this command is run as 'best effort' - I don't want the updating to stop because some packages are not available to reinstall (those will stay unmodified)

```
$ dpkg -l | grep '^ii ' | sed 's/  */\t/g' |cut -f 2,3 | sed 's/\t/=/' | xargs apt-get install --reinstall --ignore-missing
```

While testing, I also added a `--dry-run` argument to apt-get.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a reasonably simple way to go. The command to get the list of packages and their status is `dpkg --get-selections`, so you could do something like this:

```shell
dpkg --get-selections | grep '\<install$' | cut -f1 | xargs apt-get install --reinstall
```