# How to install SELinux policy manpage?

Tags: man, selinux

How to install the manpage `httpd_selinux` on CentOS 7.4?

It's not included in the packages `httpd`, `httpd-tools`, or `httpd-manual`.

A `yum whatprovides "*/httpd_selinux"` search returned no results. (Related question: [How can I find what package provides a missing man page?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269840/how-can-i-find-what-package-provides-a-missing-man-page))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SELinux policy manpages are not readily available as a package, but they can be installed using [`sepolicy`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/security-enhanced_linux-the-sepolicy-suite-sepolicy_manpage) tool:

```
sepolicy manpage -a -p /usr/local/man/man8
mandb
```