# SFTP SELinux ssh_chroot_full_access

Tags: centos, sftp, chroot, selinux

I always configured SFTP on Centos 6 like this:

https://www.linuxtechi.com/configure-chroot-sftp-in-linux/

Where in the comment this item appeared:

```
setsebool -P ssh_chroot_full_access on
```

From the docs at https://linux.die.net/man/8/ssh_selinux:

> If you want to allow fenced domain to execute ssh, you must turn on
>   the fenced_can_ssh boolean.

However, CentOS 7 complains:

> SELinux boolean ssh_chroot_full_access does not exist.

What is the proper CentOS7 way to do this?

Comment: Could you link to the documentation you refer to? Do you need that boolean since you are using *internal-sftp*. You could try if there are issues and see what `audit2why` tells (it can suggest relevant booleans too).

Comment: @sebasth I will check the audit2why, looks interesting!

Comment: The man pages hosted on linux.die.net are very old, you should refer to the man pages installed on your system ([related](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418643/how-to-install-selinux-policy-manpage/418651#418651)). I think testing the system without further configuration is the easiest way to proceed (to see if there are any errors).

Comment: Ah, yes, that makes sense. I'll just ignore it and continue configuring. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The command `getsebool -a | grep ssh` on my CentOS 7 shows

```
fenced_can_ssh --> off 
selinuxuser_use_ssh_chroot --> off
ssh_chroot_rw_homedirs --> off
ssh_keysign --> off
ssh_sysadm_login --> off
```

so based on your question the command

```
setsebool -P fenced_can_ssh on
```

should fix it.

But you could also go the "hard" way and install the `setroubleshoot-server` and `policycoreutils-python` package with:

```
yum -y install setroubleshoot-server policycoreutils-python
```

and then temporarily set SELinux mode to `permissive` with

```
setenforce Permissive
```

After that try whatever did not work previously. It should work now.

Now take a look at the following file `/var/log/audit/audit.log`. It usually shows problems SELinux found.

```
grep -i "denied" /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

If you get no denied messages in the log it is possible that SELinux thinks the event would produce to much log so it did not log it. You can enable logging of all events in this case with

```
semodule -DB
```

But make sure you turn it back to normal with `semodule -B` at the end of troubleshooting.

If you found problems you can now use the `audit2allow` tool to create a policy module for your needs. `audit2allow` has many options, so you should first read [ALLOWING ACCESS: AUDIT2ALLOW](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/sect-security-enhanced_linux-fixing_problems-allowing_access_audit2allow) to get used with `audit2allow`.

**Don't forget to turn on SELinux againg and (if changed) enable reduced logging!**

```
setenforce permissive
semodule -B
```

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow, nice approach!

Comment: On CentOS 6 I have this: `fenced_can_ssh --> off
ssh_chroot_full_access --> on`

Comment: On centos 6 we set ssh_chroot_full_access --> on, what is equivalent on centos 7 ?