# Why can I get man pages for section 1, but not for section 2 and section 3 on a google cloud VM?

Tags: centos, man, google-cloud

I'm running Centos7 on a google cloud VM. I've installed man but can get man pages only for section 1 of the manual. Even as root, I can only get man pages for section 1. For example with the section 2 nanosleep system call I get

```
[root@rg32-8 c_tests]# man 2 nanosleep
No manual entry for nanosleep in section 2
```

I also have a bare metal machine running Centos7, where I can get man pages for all sections.

What do I need to do on the google cloud machine to get man pages for all sections?

Comment: Is `man-pages` rpm installed?  If not, try `yum install man-pages`.

Comment: Possibly related: [How can I find what package provides a missing man page on CentOS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269840/how-can-i-find-what-package-provides-a-missing-man-page-on-centos)

Comment: @StephenHarris yum install man-pages did the job. Previously I did yum install man, but that obviously did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On CentOS the manpages are separate from the man command.

On CentOS7 the command

```
yum install man-db
```

will install the man software and the few man pages related to it (e.g. `manpath.1`, `whatis.1`).  Other packages may have also installed their own manpages.

However the traditional core set of manpages are in a different package; `man-pages`.  The command

```
yum install man-pages
```

will install the stuff you're looking for (including 440 section 2, 2600 section 3 pages).

If you're not sure what package supplies a file you can ask `yum`.  eg to find `chown(2)` manpage:

```
% sudo yum whatprovides '*/chown.2*'
```

This includes (amongst others)

```
man-pages-3.53-5.el7.noarch : Man (manual) pages from the Linux Documentation
                            : Project
Repo        : @base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/share/man/man2/chown.2.gz
```

(it'll also show packages for other languages such as French or Russian).