# Reinstall man pages & fix man

Tags: debian, apt, man, documentation

So in a recent fit of folly, I followed [the instructions in this answer on the Ubuntu SE page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129566/remove-documentation-to-save-hard-drive-space/401144#401144)  since I wanted to remove most of the documentation. However, I didn't read the commands well enough and missed that that those would also remove the man pages, which I didn't want.

After the damage was done, I'm now trying to figure out how to recover from my mistake. After reinstalling `man-db` and `manpages`, it still does not work though. Currently, `man cp` for example only shows a bunch of

```
~
~ 
~
```

Exiting this view of the broken manpage leaves me with an error

```
man: command exited with status 3: /usr/lib/man-db/zsoelim | /usr/lib/man-db/manconv -f UTF-8:ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8//IGNORE | preconv -e UTF-8 | tbl | nroff -mandoc -Tutf8
```

So even uninstalling certain packages and reinstalling still does not help this. Therefore, as far as I'm aware of this question is not a duplicate to questions like [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79028/debian-install-missing-man-pages) or [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1834/missing-man-pages-of-some-commands) .

**Is anyone aware of an approach to fix this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the lines matching `/usr/share/man` and `/usr/share/groff` from `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/01_nodoc`, then reinstall `groff`, `man-db`, `manpages` and any other package whose manpages you want to restore. The `cp` manpage for example is in the `coreutils` package.

Answer (score 2):

This error message can be a symptom of a recent bug in a couple of distributions (eg: Debian, [bug #890861](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=890861)), and this SO question appears in the first results from a google search.

The temporary workaround until the fix comes out is to export a variable, or to start man with said variable set:

eg:

```
MAN_DISABLE_SECCOMP=1 man man
```

or:

```
export MAN_DISABLE_SECCOMP=1
man man
```