# Docker – debian:stretch-slim – install man and view manpages

Tags: debian, docker, man

When using the [`debian:stretch`](https://hub.docker.com/_/debian/) Docker image, the [`/usr/share/man/`](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s11.html#usrsharemanManualPages) directory already contains many [manpages](https://wiki.debian.org/ManPage), and [`man`](https://ss64.com/bash/man.html) can be easily installed to view them:

```bash
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install man
$ man ls
$ man cp
```

However, when using the [`debian:stretch-slim`](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/debian#debiansuite-slim) Docker image, the `/usr/share/man/` directory is intentionally empty:

> These tags are an experiment in providing a slimmer base (removing some extra files that are normally not necessary within containers, such as man pages and documentation)

How do I populate the `/usr/share/man/` directory, so I can use `man` to view manpages for core utilities (such as `cat`, `chmod`, `chown`, `cp`, `ls`, `mkdir`, `mv`, `rm`, `tail`, etc) ?

Answer (score 13):

The [`coreutils`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/coreutils) package [populates the `/usr/share/man/man1/` directory with manpages for core utilities](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/amd64/coreutils/filelist).

However, simply running `apt-get update` and `apt-get install coreutils` is not sufficient, because [`dpkg`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/dpkg/dpkg.1.en.html) has been [configured to exclude `/usr/share/man/*`](https://github.com/debuerreotype/debuerreotype/blob/0.8/scripts/.slimify-excludes#L11), using `path-exclude` in `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/docker` (see [here](https://github.com/debuerreotype/debuerreotype/blob/0.8/scripts/debuerreotype-slimify#L51) and [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ReducingDiskFootprint#Drop_unnecessary_files)).

So the first step is to remove that line from the `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/docker` file. One way to do this is by using [`sed`](https://ss64.com/bash/sed.html):

```bash
$ sed -i '/path-exclude \/usr\/share\/man/d' /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/docker
```

`dpkg` has also been [configured to exclude `/usr/share/groff/*`](https://github.com/debuerreotype/debuerreotype/blob/0.8/scripts/.slimify-excludes#L6), and this needs to be undone too (since [`groff`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_groff) is required in order to render manpages):

```bash
$ sed -i '/path-exclude \/usr\/share\/groff/d' /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/docker
```

Now the `/usr/share/man/man1/` directory needs to be populated from the `coreutils` package. Since `coreutils` is already installed in the `debian:stretch-slim` Docker image, it needs to be reinstalled:

```bash
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install --reinstall coreutils
```

Finally, `man` can be installed and manpages can be viewed:

```bash
$ apt-get install man
$ man ls
$ man cp
```

It's also helpful to install [`less`](https://ss64.com/bash/less.html), which `man` will use for paginating the manpages, and provides a better experience than the default [`more`](https://ss64.com/bash/more.html) paginator:

```bash
$ apt-get install less
```

---

Related questions:

- [Remove documentation to save hard drive space](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129566/remove-documentation-to-save-hard-drive-space/401144#401144)
- [Installing packages without docs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541055/installing-packages-without-docs/541061#541061)
- [Reinstall man pages & fix man](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339132/reinstall-man-pages-fix-man/339134#339134)
- [How can I restore the man page for ls (/usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz)?](https://superuser.com/questions/597123/how-can-i-restore-the-man-page-for-ls-usr-share-man-man1-ls-1-gz/597125#597125)

Comment: With current Debian Stretch you need to install `man-db` instead of `man`.

Comment: I needed to install `groff-base` too

Answer (score 0):

If you want man-pages included do not use the

`debian:stretch-slim` version,

instead go for the regular

`debian:stretch`

The man-intentionally to save diskspace in the slim-version.

- https://hub.docker.com/_/debian/#Image_Variants