# `man --html` and `man --gxditview` exit with errors?

Tags: ubuntu, man, html, groff

### Problem

On my machine (Ubuntu 18.04), I am able to view `man` pages normally in the console.

However, I cannot seem to get `man --html` (`man -H`) or `man --gxditview` (`man -X`) to work.

Might anyone have any inklings as to what is wrong?

### Related Posts

- https://askubuntu.com/a/339268/692420 - Found this to realize I needed `sudo apt install groff`.
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=238227 - Mentions `MAN_DISABLE_SECCOMP`, but I tried it out and didn't seem to change my issue.
- [Reinstall man pages & fix man](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339132/reinstall-man-pages-fix-man) - This mentions reinstalling packages, but this user wasn't even able to view `man cp` on the console.
- For other posts that I've searched and found, they just had issues with their `DISPLAY`. In this case, I feel that I've discounted that possibility by opening up `firefox` and `gxditview` just fine on their own.

### Potential Workarounds

I'm guessing that I could use something like `man2html` in other posts, but if possible, would prefer to know how to fix the "builtin" setup first.

There's also `yelp man:cp`, suggested from the [above-linked post](https://askubuntu.com/a/339268/692420), which looks uber nice, so will probably stick with that for now (but hope that xref's are there...)

### Reproduction

I have "minimized" my environment variables [using the following command](https://gist.github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/6870970d68f75d23061177a52932a5d1#file-bash_helper_functions-sh-L33-L34):

```
$ alias bash-isolate='env -i HOME=$HOME DISPLAY=$DISPLAY SHELL=$SHELL TERM=$TERM USER=$USER PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin bash --norc'
$ bash-isolate

# In isolated session
$ env | sort
DISPLAY=:1
HOME=/home/eacousineau
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
PWD=/home/eacousineau
SHELL=/bin/bash
SHLVL=1
TERM=screen
USER=eacousineau
_=/usr/bin/env
```

All of my examples will be posted starting from this environment.

Here's showing that `man` normally works:

```
$ man cp | head -n 4
CP(1)                                       User Commands                                      CP(1)

NAME
       cp - copy files and directories
```

However, when I try to call `man --html=/usr/bin/firefox` or `man --gxditview`, I get the following:

```
$ which groff
/usr/bin/groff

$ firefox
# A window opens up fine and dandy.

$ man --html=/usr/bin/firefox cp
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Error: cannot open display: :1
man: couldn't execute any browser from /usr/bin/firefox

$ gxditview
# A window opens up fine and dandy, also.

$ man --gxditview cp
groff: gxditview: Signal 31 (core dumped)
man: command exited with status 1: (cd /usr/share/man && /usr/lib/man-db/zsoelim) | (cd /usr/share/man && /usr/lib/man-db/manconv -f UTF-8:ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8//IGNORE) | (cd /usr/share/man && preconv -e UTF-8) | (cd /usr/share/man && tbl) | (cd /usr/share/man && groff -mandoc -TX75 -X)
```

If I run the same commands, but precede them with `export MAN_DISABLE_SECCOMP=1`, I see no difference in behavior:

```
$ export MAN_DISABLE_SECCOMP=1
$ env | sort
DISPLAY=:1
HOME=/home/eacousineau
MAN_DISABLE_SECCOMP=1
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
PWD=/home/eacousineau
SHELL=/bin/bash
SHLVL=1
TERM=screen
USER=eacousineau
_=/usr/bin/env

$ man --html=/usr/bin/firefox cp
# Same as above.
$ man --gxditview cp
# Same as above.
```

I also tried haphazardly using `xhost +` and `xhost +local:root` (and quickly calling `xhost -` / `xhost -local:root` and terminating those sessions thereafter), but found the same behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Fix for Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Running

```
BROWSER=firefox man --html cp
```

in one terminal window and

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

in another window revealed the following output in my VM:

```
Jun 20 22:25:00 redacted kernel: [186784.927254] audit: type=1400 audit(1592684700.904:81): apparmor="DENIED" operation="file_inherit" profile="man_groff" name="/tmp/hmanwJkIBp/cp.html" pid=6943 comm="preconv" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jun 20 22:25:00 redacted kernel: [186784.960191] audit: type=1400 audit(1592684700.936:82): apparmor="DENIED" operation="file_inherit" profile="man_groff" name="/tmp/hmanwJkIBp/cp.html" pid=6944 comm="tbl" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jun 20 22:25:00 redacted kernel: [186785.004522] audit: type=1400 audit(1592684700.980:83): apparmor="DENIED" operation="file_inherit" profile="man_groff" name="/tmp/groff-regions-GzqhRi" pid=6952 comm="troff" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Jun 20 22:25:01 redacted kernel: [186785.022296] audit: type=1400 audit(1592684700.992:84): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="man_groff" name="/etc/papersize" pid=6952 comm="troff" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Jun 20 22:25:01 redacted kernel: [186785.652245] audit: type=1400 audit(1592684701.628:85): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="/usr/bin/man" pid=6958 comm="firefox" family="unix" sock_type="stream" protocol=0 requested_mask="send receive connect" denied_mask="send connect" addr=none peer_addr="@/tmp/.X11-unix/X0" peer="unconfined"
Jun 20 22:25:01 redacted kernel: [186785.654920] audit: type=1400 audit(1592684701.632:86): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="/usr/bin/man" pid=6961 comm="firefox" family="unix" sock_type="stream" protocol=0 requested_mask="send receive connect" denied_mask="send connect" addr=none peer_addr="@/tmp/.X11-unix/X0" peer="unconfined"
```

meaning `apparmor` and the profiles `man_groff` and `/usr/bin/man` are somehow involved in the non-functioning command.

Running `sudo aa-status | grep man` indeed outputs:

```
   /usr/bin/man
   /usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script
   man_filter
   man_groff
```

To disable the `man` profile and remove the AppArmor definition from the kernel, run

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.man /etc/apparmor.d/disable/
sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.man
```

and verify the output of `sudo aa-status | grep man` again. The entries `/usr/bin/man`, `man_filter` and `man_groff` should be gone.

Then run

```
BROWSER=firefox man --html cp
```

or

```
man --html=firefox cp
```

or

```
MAN_DISABLE_SECCOMP=1 man --gxditview cp
```

and enjoy.

---

**Note:** I never used AppArmor before and didn't even know it was active in my Ubuntu VM.
These links provided me with the information to disable the profile:

- [AppArmor](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor) (Ubuntu community documentation)
- [AppArmor](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/security-apparmor) (Ubuntu server documentation)

Comment: Sweet, thanks! From skimming `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.man`, I dunno the full rationale behind the conservative approach (e.g. the attack surface), but your commands worked - and thank you for the thorough detail!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to completely disable the default AppArmor profile at `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.man`, you can either edit to add the needed missing rules, or create an override at `/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.bin.man`

Using a combination of `aa-notify`, `aa-logprof` and similar tools, as described in this [excellent tutorial from Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/beginning-apparmor-profile-development#1-overview), you can find the needed rules:

```
# Needed by /usr/bin/man main profile:
#include <abstractions/nameservice>
capability sys_admin,

# Needed by man_groff child profile:
#include <abstractions/user-tmp>
/etc/papersize r,
```